# Matrix-like operations for 3D arrays in R?

Tags: arrays, r, optimization, linear-algebra, apply

I'm currently estimating a model in R using optim, but it's really slow, on the order of 30 minutes if I initialize it with zeroes.  When I profile the whole thing, I find that apply is taking the most time, which makes sense.  So that leads me to my question:

```
x.arr <- array(1:9, c(3, 10, 3))
b    <- 1:3

f <- function(x, b) {
    exp(x%*%b)
}

u.mat <- apply(x.arr, 2, f, b = b)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? x.arr is a 3D array, so it seems like there ought to be some way to use matrix operations to solve the same goal.

Additionally, I run Linux, so I assume that I can also easily do something with [mclapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html) or something, but every time that I've made the attempt, I've managed to hang my entire R session.

There's also a package, [tensor](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tensor/tensor.pdf) but everything I've tried from it so far was so far from what I was actually looking for that I wasn't even sure what I was getting back.

My linear algebra isn't the best, but something tells me there ought to be some sort of good option without using apply.

Answer (score 0):

As these things go, I found a solution that speeds it up considerably using the tensor package. (I spent 4 hours on this yesterday, but apparently today things just clicked.)

```
require(tensor)

x.arr <- array(1:9, c(3, 10, 3))
b     <- 1:3

u.mat <- exp(tensor(x.arr, b, alongA = 3, alongB = 1))
```

Which now takes me from a time of ~ 30 minutes to a time of around ~ 10 minutes.

I'm still interested if anyone has an idea of how to make it faster, of course, but maybe if someone else finds this question, this will at least be a satisfactory answer for them.